# How to check PC/LAPTOP(BIOS/Drivers) support

Tags: drivers, bios, updates

First question for me here!

I'd like to find out how to check if a PC/laptop is end of life?

For example, I have a few Toshiba Satellite Pro R50-B, the last BIOS update it was in 2020 - according to **Dynabook**, ex Toshiba - how can I know if it is still - or not - supported?

The question applies to other models such as HP, and Dell.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: How do you define EOL? If the support from the manufacturer stops? Maybe the manufacturer still offers downloads for drivers for old operating systems, but does not write drivers for newer operating systems.

Comment: Is the processor in the device EOL? That’s a good indicator

Comment: Hey, guys! Thanks for your answers. I would say in this case I mean EOL when there are no more BIOS/drivers updates. In this specific case I'd like to know if the BIOS is still being supported/updated.

Comment: I only see a BIOS update from [2018](https://support.dynabook.com/support/modelHome?freeText=1200013106&osId=3333785).

Comment: I have a BIOS update for my 2016 X1.  It depends on the vendor

Comment: Well, you can check when the latest updates came out then. Or ask the support. There's no universal way.

Comment: I just sold a still working laptop from 2010. Yea, it won't run Windows 11, but it runs Windows 10 ok. I don't know how much longer it'll run, but I've taken care of it, and it still worked when I sold it. Updates are mostly about fixing issues. Eventually you should run out of things important enough to fix, so not getting BIOS updates is not a necessarily a good rule for whether a device has reached EoL.

Answer (score 0):

> how can I know if it is still - or not - supported?

There is not any concrete answer to this.

Generally after 5 years, BIOS and Driver Updates slow down.

I have a Lenovo X1 from 2022 and it gets frequent driver updates. I have a Lenovo X1 from 2016 and it gets fewer updates. I have a Lenovo X230 from 2013 and it gets the odd update (but very few).

There were (5 years ago) 16 million combinations of computers and drivers (source: Microsoft seminar in Redmond).

All you can do is run the Manufacturer's Drive Update App and see what it produces.

Vendors will not tell you there are no more updates. They just will not have any more and it is your responsibility to check.

Comment: In addition to the above, a manufacturer can stop producing updates for their devices, because there simply is nothing to fix for them, and then a hacker finds a serious exploit 3 years later, and they decide to patch it, and a new update comes out. There's just no way to know for sure.